# Laravel 5.1 How to join two collections of objects

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

All warehouses tables have differemt number of columns. So I can't use union inside a query. But I hate this way to join this collection of objects.
There is a better (clear) way?
Thx :)

```
public function index()
{

    $warehouses1  = Farm_warehouse::all();
    $warehouses2  = Butchery_warehouse::all();
    $warehouses3  = Grape_warehouse::all();
    $warehouses4  = Iron_warehouse::all();
    $warehouses5  = Rice_warehouse::all();
    $warehouses6  = Silk_warehouse::all();
    $warehouses7  = Wood_warehouse::all();

    $warehouses2 = $warehouses1->merge($warehouses2);
    $warehouses3 = $warehouses2->merge($warehouses3);
    $warehouses4 = $warehouses3->merge($warehouses4);
    $warehouses5 = $warehouses4->merge($warehouses5);
    $warehouses6 = $warehouses5->merge($warehouses6);
    $warehouses = $warehouses6->merge($warehouses7);


    return view('warehouses.index', compact('warehouses'));

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the improvement you are looking for but couldn't you chain it together like this?

```
public function index()
{

    $warehouses  = Farm_warehouse::all();
    $warehouses->merge(Butchery_warehouse::all());
    $warehouses->merge(Grape_warehouse::all());
    $warehouses->merge(Iron_warehouse::all());
    $warehouses->merge(Rice_warehouse::all());
    $warehouses->merge(Silk_warehouse::all());
    $warehouses->merge(Wood_warehouse::all());


    return view('warehouses.index', compact('warehouses'));

}
```

I think that's a bit easier to read, but may be you can extract it out to a base Warehouse Model or try digging into the Collection class for something more fruitful. Hope this helps.